# CSS3 opacity animation does not work with 'overflow:hidden'

Tags: css, animation, opacity, css-animations

I have A Scenrio where I need to do a Fade-In Animation on a DIV, which wasn't working as desired. 
After much experiment, I found out that one of the div's has got "overflow:hidden" in the css class applied to it. If I comment the "overflow:hidden" part, the animation seems to work perfectly.
Though it fixed my problem, However, the question lingers in my mind, whether 'overflow:hidden' doesn not work with opacity animation. 
For your perusal, here's the code.

My Browser Chrome 15.0.XXX.X
My OS Windows XP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
#MainContainer {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.focussedItem {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.innerDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This is where the Problem is */
}

.optionItem {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 25px;
}

@
-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { 
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100%{opacity:1;}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;
    function KeyCheck(e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        document.getElementById("MainContainer").style.webkitAnimationDuration = "2000ms";
        document.getElementById("MainContainer").style.webkitAnimationName = "fadeIn"
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>press space to test</div>

    <div id="MainContainer" class="MainContainer">
        <div id="SubContainer" class="focussedItem"
            style="height: 290px; top: 250px;">
            <div id="OptionRing" class="innerDiv"
                style="height: 190px; top: 50px;">
                <div class="optionItem" style="top: -40px;">OPTION 1</div>
                <div class="optionItem" style="top: 10px;">OPTION 2</div>
                <div class="optionItem" style="top: 60px;">OPTION 3</div>
                <div class="optionItem" style="top: 110px;">OPTION 4</div>
                <div class="optionItem" style="top: 160px;">OPTION 5</div>
                <div class="optionItem" style="top: 210px;">OPTION 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@

-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {`

change to :

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
```

@ need in the same line

http://jsfiddle.net/wX8DW/

Overflow: hidden does not affect the result

Comment: doesn't help. even upgraded the browser to chrome 16.0.XXX.X, and its still the same. However, i must mention that, sometimes, after probably 20-30 times, the animation works perfectly, but as soon as I clear the cache, and relaunch the browser, it no more works.

Comment: I also need to mention, that I tested this in iPad Safari Browser, and the overflow:hidden is not a problem there.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my system only. i guess i'll settle with this answer as the correct one.